# Proving that a wf is logically valid/not valid.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This 2 question are from "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , exercise 2.21(g) and 2.22(i).

2.21.g. ($\exists x)(\forall y)(A^2_1(x,y) \land \lnot A^2_1(y,x) \to [A^2_1(x,x) \leftrightarrow A^2_1(y,y)])$

I have to prove that this formula is not logically valid with a counterexample.Here are the counterexamples I was able to come up with so far:

$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x = y$ 
$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x \neq y$ 
$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x < y$ 
$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x > y$ 
$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x \geq y$ 
$(A^2_1)^M(x,y) \equiv x \leq y$

But none of them seem to work though and I am all out of ideas.

This is 2.22.i.

> For all positive integers $x$, $x \leq x$.For all positive integers $x$,$y$,$z$, if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x \leq z$. For all positive integers $x$ and $y$ , $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$.Therefore, there is a positive integer $y$ such that, for all positive integers $x$, $y \leq x$.

Lets say $x\leq y \equiv A(x,y)$

There are three premises (1,2,3) and one conclusion (4).

1. $\forall x [A(x,x)]$
2. $\forall x \forall y \forall z [A(x,y) \land A(y,z) \to A(x,z)]$
3. $\forall x \forall y [A(x,y) \lor A(y,x)]$
4. $\exists y \forall x [A(y,x)]$

I have to check whether the conjunction of the premises logically imply the conclusion.

My first confusion is , why do we need (1.) here seperately ? For example , from (3.)

$\to \forall x \forall y [A(x,y) \lor A(y,x)]$ 
$\to \forall x \forall x [A(x,x) \lor A(x,x)]$ 
$\to \forall x [A(x,x) \lor A(x,x)]$ 
$\to \forall x [A(x,x)]$

Anyway , for the main problem , I thought that it might be logically implying . So I assumed the conclusion to be false , then prove one of the premises to be wrong and show a contradiction.But I wasn't able to. Maybe it is not logically implying ?

I am all out of ideas , can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2.21(g), define a two-elements domain $D = \{ 0,1 \}$ with a relation $A^D$ such that $(0,0), (0,1) \in A^D$.

Consider now $(∀y)(A(0,y) ∧ ¬A(y,0) \to [A(0,0) ↔ A(y,y)])$. We have two possible choices for $y$: $0$ and $1$.

For $0$ we have that the antecedent is false (due to $\lnot A(0,0)$) and thus the conditional is true.

But for $1$ we have that the antecedent is true while the consequent is false.

Thus, it is not true that the formula is true for every element in the domain $D$.

---

For 2.22(i), consider the set $\mathbb Z$ of integers: the three axioms are satisfied but there is no "minimum".

Comment: I guess I should have considered finite domains instead of just infinite domains .Thanks for the response. Can you also resolve the apparent confusion I was having with the second question? (" why do we need (1.) here seperately").

Comment: @Prithubiswas - not clear... What is (1)? The first axiom? The questions asks if the conclusion is "logically implied" by the premises. IMO the exercise is aimed at understanding logical implication, because if we think in terms of natural numbers, we are tempted to answer YES.

Comment: What I meant is that maybe the question could have been asked without the (1) axiom , because the (1) axiom can be proven already from the (3) axiom .So maybe the (1) axiom is unnessesary for the question.Is there something wrong with this reasoning ?

Comment: The question could have been "_For all positive integers $x,y,z,$ if $x≤y$ and $y≤z$, then $x≤z$. For all positive integers $x$ and $y$ , $x≤y$ or $y≤x$.Therefore, there is a positive integer $y$ such that, for all positive integers $x$, $y≤x$_". Instead of "_For all positive integers $x$, $x≤x$.For all positive integers $x,y,z,$ if $x≤y$ and $y≤z$, then $x≤z$. For all positive integers $x$ and $y$ , $x≤y$ or $y≤x$.Therefore, there is a positive integer $y$ such that, for all positive integers $x$, $y≤x$_".

Comment: So , where is the flaw in my reasoning ? [I assumed you meant that there is something wrong].

Comment: You cannot prove that 2+3+ (not-4) imply a contra, because they are satisfied bu $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: "You said that 1 follows from 2 and 3. Correct." , My Bad, I thought you said the exact opposite. That settles the confusion for me :)